# Estou montando uma página HTML e quero redirecionar o 'cliente' caso o usuário e a senha digitados estejam corretos

Tags: javascript, html

Possuo 3 input, um de tipo email e outro de tipo password:

```
              <input id="usuario" type="email" placeholder="Usuário">

              <input id="senha" type="password" placeholder="Senha">
```

E um submit o qual fará a validação:

```
<input id="logar" type="submit" value="Entrar" class="enviar" onclick="return Redirecionar()">
```

Estou tentando validar utilizando um arquivo js:

```
var botaoAdicionar = document.querySelector("#logar");
        botaoAdicionar.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

        var capturando = "";
        function Redirecionar() {

        capturando = document.getElementById('usuaario').value;
        capturando = document.getElementById('senhaa').value;

        document.getElementById('capturando').innerHTML = capturando;

        if (usuario == "teste@hotmail.com" && senha == "123") {
        function Redirecionar() {
        window.location.href="menu.html";

            }
        }

        else{
            alert("Dados incorretos! Por favor, tente novamente.");

            }   
        }
 });
```

Entretanto a página apenas atualiza, já de várias formas e não consigo :/
Então quem puder me ajudar :) Agradeço

Comment: Adiciona `event.preventDefault();` no começo da função do click, para evitar a atualização da página. Também pode trocar o `type="submit"` para `type="button"`.

Comment: Vc está chamando uma função que está dentro da função do evento click e declarou a mesma função 2 vezes, uma dentro da outra. Além de outros problemas, como declarando a variável `capturando` 2 vezes com valores diferentes. Tem que refazer o código.

Comment: Ah sim, eu já havia colocado essa linha, porém acabei retirando sem querer conforme fui tentando. Infelizmente esse não é o problema.

Comment: Também tem erros de digitação em "usuaario" e "senhaa".

Comment: Entendi, então é desnecessário que eu utilize 2 funções para esse caso, certo?

Comment: Sim, já estavam corretos no arquivo original, conforme eu disse já havia feito várias modificações e acabei enviando uma antiga sem as devidas correções.

Comment: Se você adiciona o _event listener_ no JS, não faz sentido o `onclick="return Redirecionar()"` no botão. Além disso você está criando funções dentro do callback que não são usadas. Precisa dar uma estudada nos escopos e eventos do JS, aqui no SOpt tem bastante conteúdo relacionado

Comment: Obrigado !!!!! deu certo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mudando o type para button, e somente com `EventListener`, você já consegue chamar a função necessária para essa validação.

Você pode tentar algo parecido com isso:

```js
var botaoAdicionar = document.querySelector("#logar");

botaoAdicionar.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

   var campoUsuario = document.getElementById('usuario').value;
   var campoSenha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
          
   if (campoUsuario == "teste@hotmail.com" && campoSenha == "123") 
       window.location.href="menu.html";
   else
       alert("Dados incorretos! Por favor, tente novamente.");     
});
```

```html
<input id="usuario" type="email" placeholder="Usuário">

<input id="senha" type="password" placeholder="Senha">

<input id="logar" type="button" value="Entrar" class="enviar">
```

Comment: Para novo programador aqui no Stack, resposta perfeita !

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado !!